# Adding feature object to PostGIS feature type from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, features, rest

I am trying to set up a system that will post feature objects periodically to a PostGIS db and display them via GeoServer and OpenLayers on a web site.
Is it possible to add the new feature objects to the db via GeoServer using the REST API or geoserver-manager (my system is Java based) or will I have to add the features directly into the PostGIS db?

Comment: could you use wfs-t?

Comment: Thank you, that must be it. I guess I would blame my inability to find the answer in the docs on me being a complete newb at GIS and GeoServer. The multitude of new words...

Comment: While waiting for a response to this question I created code that inserts my features into the db directly using postgresql jdbc. Which is the preferred way of doing this among all you GIS gurus, the jdbc or wfs-t way?

Comment: it would depend on where your data is coming from

Comment: By the way iant, if you answer my question "officially" I'll get you the cred that you deserve.

Comment: Well, in my case the data is coming from a java back end that in turn receives coordinates from an Android app continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding the data from a client then you should probably use WFS-T - GeoServer will then "know" to update any cached tiles that include the layer. However if you are collecting the data from (or via) a process on the server then doing a direct write to the database will be more efficient (saves the change to GML and back). You might find [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) helpful for talking to PostGIS databases.